# How to fill a CartoPy map with a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cartopy

I have a Cartopy Map which looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, there is a grid overlaid which is 14x20 grid squares in size.

I also have a data frame, called df, which is also 14x20:

```
         0         1         2   ...        17        18        19
0        NaN       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN
1        NaN       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN
2   0.022079  0.017996  0.017996  ...  0.011409  0.011409  0.011409
3   0.022079  0.017996  0.017996  ...  0.011409  0.011409  0.011409
4   0.022079  0.017996  0.017996  ...  0.011409  0.011409  0.011409
5   0.022079  0.017996  0.017996  ...  0.011409  0.011409  0.011409
6   0.021927  0.020711  0.020711  ...  0.016651  0.016651  0.016651
7   0.021927  0.020711  0.020711  ...  0.016651  0.016651  0.016651
8   0.021927  0.020711  0.020711  ...  0.016651  0.016651  0.016651
9   0.021927  0.020711  0.020711  ...  0.016651  0.016651  0.016651
10  0.019435  0.021574  0.021574  ...  0.013323  0.013323  0.013323
11  0.019435  0.021574  0.021574  ...  0.013323  0.013323  0.013323
12  0.019435  0.021574  0.021574  ...  0.013323  0.013323  0.013323
13  0.019435  0.021574  0.021574  ...  0.013323  0.013323  0.013323

[14 rows x 20 columns]
```

I'm trying to fill the dataframe values into the grid cells to plot a Cartopy map. Here's what I've tried:

```
precip_full1 = xr.open_dataset('era_yr1979.nc')

lon = precip_full1.variables['longitude'][:]
lat = precip_full1.variables['latitude'][:]

lon2d, lat2d = np.meshgrid(lon, lat)


plt.figure(figsize=(6,5))
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.set_extent([-15,-10,6.5,10])
ax.coastlines()
ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAND)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAKES)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.RIVERS)


ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS)
plt.title('Average Rainfall over Sierra Leone')

gl = ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True, xlocs=np.arange(-180,180,0.25), ylocs=np.arange(-90,90,0.25),linewidth=0.4)
gl.top_labels   = False
gl.right_labels = False

plot = plt.contourf(lon2d, lat2d, df, cmap = 'YlOrRd', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

to which I get:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Does anyone know how I could make this work?

EDIT:

Printing Lon and Lat gives:

```
print(lon)

<xarray.IndexVariable 'longitude' (longitude: 21)>
array([-15.  , -14.75, -14.5 , -14.25, -14.  , -13.75, -13.5 , -13.25, -13.  ,
       -12.75, -12.5 , -12.25, -12.  , -11.75, -11.5 , -11.25, -11.  , -10.75,
       -10.5 , -10.25, -10.  ], dtype=float32)
Attributes:
    units:      degrees_east
    long_name:  longitude


print(lat)

<xarray.IndexVariable 'latitude' (latitude: 15)>
array([10.  ,  9.75,  9.5 ,  9.25,  9.  ,  8.75,  8.5 ,  8.25,  8.  ,  7.75,
        7.5 ,  7.25,  7.  ,  6.75,  6.5 ], dtype=float32)
Attributes:
    units:      degrees_north
    long_name:  latitude
```

Comment: What is your code that defines lon, lat?

Comment: I've just updated the question to include the code for it, hope that helps

Comment: What do you get from `print(lat)` and `print(lon)` ?

Comment: Updated the question with these values... Do you think I need to rename my columns and rows to the various lat/long values to make it work?

Comment: The problem is on `df` in the line of code `plt.contourf(lon2d, lat2d, df, ...`.  In this case, the parameters: `lon2d, lat2d, df` need to have the same shape. That is lon2d.shape==df.shape. If it is, another problem may arise due to 'NaN' values.

Comment: if you're interested you could give [EOmaps](https://github.com/raphaelquast/EOmaps) a try... it uses cartopy under the hood but greatly simplifies the creation of maps based on 1D or 2D datasets (or mixtues of 1D coordinates and 2D datasets) with or without NaN's